# Unable to identify strange whitespace character in MSSQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ascii, non-ascii-characters

We have a process that reads an XML file into our database and inserts any rows that aren't currently in another table to that table.

This process also has a trigger to write to an audit table and a nightly snapshot is also held in another table.

In the XML holding table a field looks like `1234567890123456` but it exists on our live table as `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6`. Those spaces will not be removed by any combination of `REPLACE` functions. We have tried all `CHAR` values and it does not recognise the character. The audit table and nightly snapshot, however, contain the correct values.

Similarly, if we run a comparison between `SELECT CASE WHEN '1234567890123456' = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`, this returns 1, so they match. However `LEN('1234567890123456')` is 16 and `LEN('1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ')` is 32.

We have ran some queries to loop through the characters in the field and output the ASCII and Unicode values for the characters. The digits return the correct ASCII/Unicode values, but this random whitespace character does not return a value.

An example of the incorrectly displayed one is `0x35000000320000003800000036000000380000003300000039000000370000003800000037000000330000003000000035000000340000003000000033000000` and a correct one is `0x3500320038003600380033003200300030003000360033003600380036003000`. Both were added by the same means on the same day. One has the extra bytes, the other is fine.

How can we identify this character and get rid of it? Is there a reason this would have been inserted originally? How can we avoid this in future?

Comment: You can use the `ASCII()` function to see what the ASCII value of hte character is.

Comment: @GordonLinoff As I mentioned, we have looped through each character in the string and ran `ASCII()` against it. The digits returned the correct value, these whitespaces returned nothing.

Comment: If it's just numbers, you could use something like [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21166/how-can-i-strip-non-numeric-characters-out-of-a-string)

Comment: One experiment you could try is using the `convert` function in order to convert the text to varchar and see what you'll get.

Comment: You could try casting to VARBINARY to get the hexadecimal value.

Comment: There may be an encoding interpretation problem somewhere. If it is stored as UTF-16 and then displayed as, say, ASCII, there will be blanks shown which do not exist. The bytes of UTF-16 (LE) for "1234" are 31 00 32 00 33 00 34 00 (hex).

Comment: @DavidG I do have a function just like that that I have used but it still returns the string with the whitespace.

Comment: Are you sure it's whitespace and not just unicode? How are you displaying the value? Is it a `varchar` column instead of `nvarchar` or something like that?

Comment: @Renato I've converted to/from varchar/nvarchar in numerous ways but it does not change the output.

Comment: How are you querying the database to see these results. What client? Is the client set up to display unicode? Is the connection the client is using to connect set up for it? It absolutely 100% sounds like you are viewing UTF16LE data on an ASCII platform. You say you've converted back and forth in the database so this does raise a flag that this isn't the case, but the fact that you are getting back two characters instead of one HIGHLY suggests that you are viewing a fixed 2-byte character set, which is almost definitely UTF16LE. Instead of hitting it with `Len()` try `DataLength()`.

Comment: In other words, there is no "Whitespace". `"1" = "1 "` and it's merely an issue of displaying the character set in whatever application you are using to display it. I suspect if you do `DATALENGTH(yourfield)` you will get back twice the result of `LEN(yourfield)`.

Comment: @DavidG It is an `nvarchar` column and I have tried every number of casts and converts to get it to display correctly.

Comment: @JNevill Yes! `LEN(field)` is half of `DATALENGTH(field)` So what causes this issue and how do we resolve it? But in saying that, `LEN(field)` is still double what we expect, therefore `DATALENGTH(field)` would be 4 times the length expected.

Comment: It's not an issue in your database, it's an issue with either your SQL client or your connection to the database. One of them is not set up to handle the unicode that it's being handed (most likely). Check your client's settings for that connection. If you are using an ODBC DSN to connect, then check through that to insure that any box or drop down that smells like unicode (As opposed to ASCII/LATIN/ETC) is checked.

Comment: We are using a native SQL server connection in SSMS. But this is only an issue in 2 dozen cases, that we know of, out of over 1.2 million rows. The `LEN` and `DATALENGTH` values are different for ALL records in the table, but there are only a handful that are displaying incorrectly.

Comment: @AndrewMorton No, they are literally digits `CHAR(32)` etc. These display differently in SSMS. Vast majority of rows have correct display, only a handful are displayed incorrectly.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It is always the same rows that are displaying incorrectly in SSMS. There are a few web applications that display these rows correctly and a few windows forms applications that display them with the "phantom" space. They all use the same connection string and methods to retrieve the data.

Comment: @anothershrubery Can you examine an entry which does display correctly and see if it has something which the faulty ones don't? E.g. it might start with the bytes FF FE.

Comment: @AndrewMorton An example of the incorrectly displayed one is `0x35000000320000003800000036000000380000003300000039000000370000003800000037000000330000003000000035000000340000003000000033000000` and a correct one is `0x3500320038003600380033003200300030003000360033003600380036003000`. Both were added by the same means on the same day. One has the extra bytes, the other is fine.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column in your "XML Holding" table and how do you copy this to your live table. If I understand your question correctly, the data looks OK in both your "XML Holding" table and your "Audit" table, but isn't looking right in your "Live" table. Is it something like a collation setting on whatever connection is being used to transfer information between your XML holding and Live tables?

Answer (score 1):

**Data entry**

It looks like some null (i.e. Char(0)) characters have got into the data.

If the data was supposed to be ASCII when it was entered but UTF-16 data got, then it could be:

Entered character codes: `48` `00`
Sent to database: `48 00` `00 00`

To avoid that, remove disallowed characters as the first step in processing the input, say by using a regex to replace [\x00-\x1F] with an empty string.

**Data repair**

Search for entries which a Char(0) in them to confirm that they can be found that way.

If so, replace the Char(0) with an empty string.

If that doesn't work, you could convert the data to the format '0x35000000320000003800000036000000380000003300000039000000370000003800000037000000330000003000000035000000340000003000000033000000', replace '000000' with '00', and then convert back.

Comment: Searching for entries with `CHAR(0)` returns all entries. Similarly, trying to replace `CHAR(0)` with an empty string doesn't do anything. We are working on making sure they don't go in to the database in the first place, but it's trying to identify the one's that are in there, and rectifying them, that is the current issue.

Comment: @anothershrubery Well that's a nuisance. Based on you being able to get a hex representation of the string, I suggested another possible method.